# Prototype's function is not defined

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am new to the concept of prototypes in JavaScript. It is confusing to me, as there seem to be many ways of doing prototype 'inheritance'. Coming from a Java background, my code is mostly structured like classical OOP, as this is the way I can understand it easily.

I want to call a function defined in the prototype, but I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: getShape is not defined`. I am not even sure if I am doing this prototype thing correctly.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
function mouseOverAnimation($main,svgId) {
    this.svg = getShape(svgId,$main); // this line works

    function getShape(shapeId,parent) {
        if (parent == undefined) { parent = svg; }
        var shape = parent.find(shapeId);
        return shape;
    }
}

function someAnimationTest($main) {
    this.prototype = new mouseOverAnimation($main,'#icon1');
    this.ball1 = getShape('#ball1'); // this line is giving me the error
}

new someAnimationTest($('body'));
```

To explain shortly what I am trying to do: I have multiple svg icons and each one needs an animation on mouse-over. As the code for the animation is mostly the same, except for the specific movements, I figured using a prototype would be a good idea. The first thing I need to do for every icon is getting vars for every shape that I need to move independently. This is what I am trying to do with the `getShape()` function.

Is the `getShape()` function actually inherited by calling `this.prototype = new mouseOverAnimation()`? How should I call it?

Appendage with some side questions that may not be related to the main issue:

I am fairly new to more complex JavaScript. Therefor I am not sure of my use of `this`, `prototype` and the way I am trying to do function 'overloading'. Please feel free to correct me on anything that isn't really ok. Also, there is the use of jQuery in this snippet, because it is included in the library I am using for animation and it was used like this in an example I have used. However, for this instance, it is really not needed I think. Is it ok to still use this `$('body')` for simplicity's sake or is it better to change this to vanilla JS?

Comment: A `new mouseOverAnimation(…)` instance would inherit its properties from `mouseOverAnimation.prototype`. Local variables are *never* inherited. I don't think your `someAnimationTest` even should inherit anything.

Comment: It is clear to me that I don't understand this prototypical inheritance at all. I need to go back to study it more. Any advice on some good sources for this?
I have many vars and functions in `mouseOverAnimation()` that I need to inherit. I really need y other functions to extend `mouseOverAnimation()` to inherit all of these. I am probably too stuck in classic OOP concept right now.

Comment: I don't even see why `getShape` should be a *method* of the animation object at all. It looks like it would fit much better as a static helper function, which could be called from anywhere as well.

Comment: I wanted to put `getShape` in there so I don't have to pass the `svg` variable every time I call it.

Comment: Ah, I missed you're using `svg` in there. But it's not a variable - it's an object property! You need to access it using `this.svg`.

Comment: Thank you. I am finding that my JavaScript knowledge is more of a mess than I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to call a function defined in the prototype, but I am getting
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: getShape is not defined.

You are getting this error since there is no `getShape` method in the `someAnimationTest` method's scope.

> Is the getShape() function actually inherited by calling
>   this.prototype = new mouseOverAnimation()?

`getShape` method is not inherited since *it is not a property* of `mouseOverAnimation`'s prototype.

> How should I call it?

You need to expose `getShape` method as `mouseOverAnimation`'s property

```
function mouseOverAnimation($main,svgId) {
    this.getShape = function (shapeId,parent) { 
        if (parent == undefined) { parent = svg; }
        var shape = parent.find(shapeId);
        return shape;
    }
    this.svg = this.getShape(svgId,$main); // this line works    
}
```

and invoke it as

```
function someAnimationTest($main) {
    this.moaInstance = new mouseOverAnimation($main,'#icon1'); //not using this.prototype as this has nothing to do with prototypical inheritence 
    this.ball1 = this.moaInstance.getShape('#ball1'); //notice that method is invoked via the instance of mouseOverAnimation 'this.moaInstance' 
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend to avoid a `this.prototype` property - it will only lead to confusion as it has nothing to do with prototypical inheritance.

Comment: Typed this before your edit: This gives me the `Uncaught ReferenceError` on line 2. I changed line 2 to `this.svg = this.getShape(svgId,$main);` and moved the function declaration before that line, so it is only called after it is declared. Otherwise it gives me `TypeError: this.getShape is not a function`. Don't really understand why.

Now I have more errors that seem to be due to the fact that I don't understand this type of inheritance. You are saying this has nothing to due with prototypical inheritance, but I think I need it to, because I have other many vars and functions to inherit.

Comment: @Rick `this.getShape` needs to be defined before it can be invoked. it has nothing to do with inheritence yet.